# How to position an XML element half in between two other elements?

Tags: android, xml

In XML there is

```
<Button  android:id="@+id/Btn1"
    android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="50dp"  
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
```

to position elements half in between the top and buttom of the screen.

Is there also a way to `position a Button Btn2 right in between Btn1 and the top or buttom` of the screen ?
And then how to position Button `Btn3 right half between Btn1 and Btn2`?

EDIT: I need this in a RELATIVE LAYOUT
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply the whole layout don't miss any point from below. and it will work for all the screen size android phones.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I do this in a relative layout?

Comment: relative layout will not lead to the same result. try this only